# Store value in hidden field

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-4

I'm try to store a value in a hidden input field using javaScript and laravel 4 but not know how. My code is as follows

This is javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myfunction(txt) { 
    document.getElementById("avatar_id").innerHTML = txt

} 
</script>
```

and laravel code is as follows

```
 <img src="" onclick="myfunction({{ $avatars->id }})"/>

{{ Form::hidden('avatar_id', 'txt') }}
```

Comment: not working hidden value show like this <input id="avatar_id" type="hidden" value="txt" name="avatar_id">2</input>

Comment: id 2 store in value = 2 like this but hidden value show like this <input id="avatar_id" type="hidden" value="txt" name="avatar_id">2</input>

Comment: See my answer,you don't need text in your hidden field, change the `value` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Form::hidden($name,$value)` the first parameter is the name of the input, in order to get it as an element by id in javascript you must provide one, `Form::hidden($name ,$value ,['id' => 'avatar_id'])`.

Try this

```
 <img src="" data-id="{{ $avatars->id }}" onclick="myfunction(this.data-id)"/>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function myfunction(id) { 

    console.log("myfunction is called and has id " + id);    

    document.getElementById("avatar_id").value = id;
} 
</script>
```

Comment: @user3825129 Change your javascript code, instead of `.innerHTML` to `.value`.